# How can I make the new html 5 datalist input open immediately?

Tags: jquery, html

Question is hard to understand and English is not my native language, I'll do my best.
So the new html tag `<datalist>` allows me to create an input field with a dropdown menu (actually not that sure how to call it).

The first time the page is loaded there is only:

```
<input list='Chemikalienliste' class="input_search" />
<datalist id='Chemikalienliste'></datalist>
<a href="#" class="add_button">+</a>
```

As a result there is no dropdown menu when you first click it. (thats good!)
When the user is typing a sign into the input field it generates a few `<option>` tags, buuuut does not drop the menu. I have to type a second sign first.

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    suchergebnis = suchergebnis+ "<option value='"+data[i].Trvialname+" ("+data[i].Chemischername+")"+"' />";   
}           
input_search.parent(".add").children("#Chemikalienliste").children("option").remove(); //deletes all options
input_search.parent(".add").children("#Chemikalienliste").append(suchergebnis);//adds new options
```

The entire Code

```
$(".input_search").focus().keyup(function(){ //user types something
    var input_search = $(this);
    var searchstring = input_search.val();
    $.ajax({
        url:"api.php",
        data:"search="+searchstring,
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(data){ //recieve data
            var suchergebnis = "";
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                suchergebnis = suchergebnis+ "<option value='"+data[i].Trvialname+" ("+data[i].Chemischername+")"+"' />";   
            }           
            input_search.parent(".add").children("#Chemikalienliste").children("option").remove();
            input_search.parent(".add").children("#Chemikalienliste").append(suchergebnis);
            input_search.focus();
        },

        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $("#output").append("<span class='message'>[ajax]</span> <span class='failed'>Error:</span> XMLHttpRequest " + XMLHttpRequest[0] + " errorThrown: " + errorThrown +" textstatus : " +                                                                                                textStatus+" <br />");     
        }
    });
});
```

If there are any other options to create something like that google search input field, please tell me.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622076/making-html5-datalist-visible-when-focus-event-fires-on-input

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer here? If so I can look into it

Answer (score 0):

You have to empty the options before doing the ajax query, you can also simplify the insertion of the options

```
$(".input_search").focus().keyup(function(){ //user types something
    var input_search = this;
    $(input_search).next().empty();
    $.ajax({
        url:"api.php",
        data:"search="+$(input_search).val(),
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(data){ //recieve data
            
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                $('<option>' + data[i].Trvialname + '</option>').appendTo($(input_search).next());
            }           
        },

        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $("#output").append("<span class='message'>[ajax]</span> <span class='failed'>Error:</span> XMLHttpRequest " + XMLHttpRequest[0] + " errorThrown: " + errorThrown +" textstatus : " +                                                                                                textStatus+" <br />");     
        }
    });
});
```