# Open a datalist on focus

Tags: jquery, html

My datalist should open on focus (no need to doubleclick). Can i do this with jQuery without extra plugins?

```html
<input list="browsers">
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

Why this is not default? I found no answer or solution for this so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically make datalist of input\[type=url\] appear with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16133661/programmatically-make-datalist-of-inputtype-url-appear-with-javascript)

Comment: FYI this behaviour already happens in Chrome 69

Comment: Firefox is not showing datalist on focus

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519123/how-can-i-make-the-new-html-5-datalist-input-open-immediately)

The suggestion is that since you are using jquery anyway, try using the jquery ui autocomplete control as you will have more control over it with jquery.  Then you can put your commands in an $("#browsers").focus(...) event for the control.

Answer (score 0):

Since datalist is not supported and handled the same way in all browsers, I switched to another solution, which does exactly what i wanted.

https://rmm5t.github.io/jquery-flexselect/

Maybe some of you will use this too.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input list="browsers" id="search">
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>

$("#search").on("mouseover", function() {
    if ($(this).val()) {
        $(this).val('');
    }else {
        $(this).focus();
    }
});
```

This should do the trick!